# You and your friend live 7 miles apart. She says that it is -7 miles from her house to your house and miles from your house to her house.

Tags: geometry

You and your friend live 7 miles apart. She says that it is -7 miles from her house to your house and  miles from your house to her house. What is the error in this argument? Explain how you would correct this statement and give an example when your friend's argument would be correct.

Above is the question.
It is clear that distance can't be negative so the statement is wrong. But the question is asking for example when the given statement is correct.
But I think that the given statement will never be correct since distance can't be negative.
What do you think?
Thanks for your time

Comment: You don't say how far it is from your house to her house. It looks like that was supposed to be +7.

Comment: What is meant by "and miles from your house to her house"?  Is there a word or two missing?

Comment: Sounds a lot like an exam question.

Comment: Unless direction was assigned somehow (say, the houses are aligned east to west, and eastward is "positive" distance and westward is "negative" distance), then this doesn't seem like too straightforward of a question, unfortunately. The nice thing about a metric is its symmetry (the distance between point A and point B is the same as the distance between point B and A, so it doesn't matter which point you start "measuring" from), so I guess you could say something about this.